# Insert com monthCalendar no banco de dados MySql e C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Preciso fazer um `insert` da data com o `monthCalendar` em `C#` no banco de dados `MySQL`, só que o formato da data do `MySQL` é (`yyyy-MM-dd`) e já modifiquei o codigo :

Modifiquei o modo de entrada (`yyyy-MM-dd`)

```
cadast.Dataa=Convert.ToDateTime(monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

E modifiquei na **classe** que faz o `insert` no banco de dados:

> `string inserir = "INSERT INTO consultas (Dataa,Horario, cd_paciente, cro, cd_procedimento) values (str_to_date('" + cadast.Dataa + "','%Y-%m-%d'),'"+cadast.Horario+ "', '" + cadast.cd_paciente + "','" + cadast.cro + "' ,'" + cadast.cd_procedimento + "')";`

E ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Erro de comandosIncorrect datetime value: '30/11/2016 00:00:00' for function str_to_date.

Modifiquei novamente o `insert` para:

> `string inserir = "INSERT INTO consultas (Dataa,Horario, cd_paciente, cro, cd_procedimento) values (str_to_date('" + cadast.Dataa + "','%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p'),'"+cadast.Horario+ "', '" + cadast.cd_paciente + "','" + cadast.cro + "' ,'" + cadast.cd_procedimento + "')";`

e modifiquei no campo do `calendario(MonthCalendar)` para ver se o problema era nele:

```
cadast.Dataa=
   Convert.ToDateTime(monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date.ToString("%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s%p"));
```

Dai ele apresentou o seguinte **erro**:

> A cadeia de caracteres não foi reconhecida como um DateTime válido. Há uma palavra desconhecida que começa no índice 0.

Também não funcionou já tentei de todas as formas possíveis e até agora não obtive exito, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

É recomendado sempre utilizar `Parameterized Query` quando estiver fazendo execução de comandos SQL que possuam parâmetros. Desta forma você evita problemas de segurança como [SQL Injection](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL) e de quebra não precisa se preocupar com formatação de dados, evitando problemas como este que você relatou.

Veja só um exemplo

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  conn.Open();
  using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO consultas (nome, data) values (@nome @data)", conn)) 
  {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Jon Snow";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

Note que estamos passando um objeto do tipo `DateTime` para nosso comando sem fazer qualquer tipo de formatação.

Comment: sim, só que meu código já está feito, não gostaria de mexer estrutura dele, pq está funcionando perfeitamente...só que o problema é que na utilização do monthcalendar não está aceitando a entrada de data que estou passando no codigo para ele.

Comment: @AndressaSantos siga esse resposta e muitas outras aqui com esse estilo, porque, ele faz a conversão automática internamente na gravação do dado na tabela, em mude o que já fez, mexa na estrutura, isso é importante para o seu aprendizado e crescimento. Essa dica vai solucionar seus problemas não só de agora mais futuros. +1 pela resposta

Comment: Tudo bem, obrigado...vou tentar mudar e dar uma pesquisada aqui..Obrigada

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite,

Eu conseguir arrumar esse problema da data eu vou postar meu código aqui, caso alguém precise de ajuda no futuro.

A solução foi: continuei com o campo Dataa no banco Mysql como date e  na programação deixei a data como string e mudei o modo de entrada da data no monthCalendar assim:

```
//Deixei como string, e mudei o modo de entrada da data no monthCalendar
       cadast.Dataa = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

O Código inteiro ficou assim:

`//classe 
 class cadas_consulta
    {`

```
//Deixei a data como string
    private string nDataa;



    public string Dataa
    {

        get { return nDataa; }
        set { nDataa = value; }
    }
```

`//classe
 class dal_consulta
    { private MySqlConnection conexao;`

```
     public void cadastro(cadas_consulta cadast)
     {
         string caminho = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=odonto_system;UID=root;PASSWORD=;";

         try
         {

             conexao = new MySqlConnection(caminho);
             conexao.Open();

             string inserir = "INSERT INTO consultas (Dataa,Horario, cd_paciente, cro, cd_procedimento) values ('" + cadast.Dataa + "','"+cadast.Horario+ "', '" + cadast.cd_paciente + "','" + cadast.cro + "' ,'" + cadast.cd_procedimento + "')";



             MySqlCommand comandos = new MySqlCommand(inserir, conexao);

             comandos.ExecuteNonQuery();
             MessageBox.Show("Consulta Cadastrada com Sucesso!");
             conexao.Close();

         }

         catch (Exception ex)
         {

             throw new Exception("Erro de comandos" + ex.Message);
         }
     }
}
```

`//inserir no botão
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {`

```
        cadas_consulta cadast = new cadas_consulta();
        dal_consulta daa = new dal_consulta();
```

`//Deixei como string também, e mudei o modo de entrada da data para padrão do banco MySql
           cadast.Dataa = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

```
        daa.cadastro(cadast);


    }`
```

Agradeço a todos que ajudaram, pois as respostas de vcs nos ajudam a estudar mais e pesquisar.

Obrigada!